# How to work out the load of an SQL

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I am investigating some SQLs in my java application. I want to know if it is possible to find the load of an SQL. Usually I count SQLs and try and reduce the numbers of them. This is not always the correct way though. I could have it where if I run two SQLs this could be faster than running one SQL that combines the two previous SQLs. Is it possible for me to find out the hit/load of a particular SQL?

I am using Oracle and have hibernate sitting between the DB and the java layer.

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

Comment: Would execution plan help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWR and ASH reports will help you find out the most significant SQLs that are putting load on your Database in different aspects (CPU, Elapsed Time, I/O etc...)